# Get table column names in MySQL?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Is there a way to grab the columns name of a table in MySQL using PHP?

Answer (score 758, accepted):

You can use [DESCRIBE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/describe.html):

```
DESCRIBE my_table;
```

Or in newer versions you can use [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html):

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';
```

Or you can use [SHOW COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html):

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM my_table;
```

Or to get column names with comma in a line:

```
SELECT group_concat(COLUMN_NAME)
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';
```

Comment: DESCRIBE is actually a shortcut for SHOW COLUMNS (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/describe.html)

Comment: @svens yeah, DESCRIBES is simpler, SHOW COLUMNS gives you more options

Comment: I would vote for the Information_Schema version, since this syntax is supported by most major databases.  Best to only learn 1 way if you have to.

Comment: +1 I wanted to select table names where a column exist I did `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'col_name';`

Comment: @Kibbee, really? I thought "INFORMATION_SCHEMA" was a MySQL proprietary asset? So it is a SQL standard that all database systems implement?

Comment: save bytes by using `desc my_table;` :-)

Comment: @Greg, Why choose `describe` instead of `desc`?

Comment: down-voted by mistake ... can you please do any update to be able to undo it ... it is really very useful

Comment: `DESC` for describe can be easily confused with `DESC` for descending. The nominal amount of bytes you save for the lack of readability is not worth it.

Comment: `Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'businesses' in 'where clause'`

Comment: group_concat(COLUMN_NAME ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION), for ordering column like original

Answer (score 48):

The following SQL statements are nearly equivalent:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name'
  [AND table_schema = 'db_name']
  [AND column_name LIKE 'wild']

SHOW COLUMNS
FROM tbl_name
[FROM db_name]
[LIKE 'wild']
```

Reference: [INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html)

Comment: Why do you say "nearly"?

Comment: @Pacerier For one thing, the second one won't work as a subquery.

Comment: @WAF, I think he meant something else altogether, not that.

Comment: In my quick test, `SHOW COLUMNS` returns a table containing the column names, types, etc, while `SELECT COLUMN NAME` returns just the column names.

Answer (score 21):

I made a PDO function which returns all the column names in an simple array.

```
public function getColumnNames($table){
    $sql = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = :table";
    try {
        $core = Core::getInstance();
        $stmt = $core->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':table', $table, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $output = array();
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $output[] = $row['COLUMN_NAME'];                
        }
        return $output; 
    }

    catch(PDOException $pe) {
        trigger_error('Could not connect to MySQL database. ' . $pe->getMessage() , E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

The output will be an array:

```
Array (
[0] => id
[1] => name
[2] => email
[3] => shoe_size
[4] => likes
... )
```

Sorry for the necro but I like my function ;)

P.S. I have not included the class Core but you can use your own class.. D.S.

Comment: What's with the upper-case fetish?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with answering an old question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks. For the output I used this way:
$columns = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return array_column($columns, 'COLUMN_NAME');

Answer (score 8):

There's also this if you prefer:

```
mysql_query('SHOW COLUMNS FROM tableName');
```

Answer (score 7):

This solution is from command line mysql

```
mysql>USE information_schema;
```

In below query just change <--DATABASE_NAME--> to your database and <--TABLENAME--> to your table name where you just want Field values of DESCRIBE statement

```
mysql> SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '<--DATABASE_NAME-->' AND   TABLE_NAME='<--TABLENAME-->';
```

Answer (score 5):

It's also interesting to note that you can use
`EXPLAIN table_name` which is synonymous with `DESCRIBE table_name` and `SHOW COLUMNS FROM table_name`
although [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) is more commonly used to obtain information about the query execution plan.

Answer (score 5):

I needed column names as a flat array, while the other answers returned associative arrays, so I used:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost',$db_user,$db_pw,$db_name);
$table = 'people';

/**
* Get the column names for a mysql table
**/

function get_column_names($con, $table) {
  $sql = 'DESCRIBE '.$table;
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

  $rows = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row['Field'];
  }

  return $rows;
}

$col_names = function get_column_names($con, $table);
```

$col_names now equals:

```
(
    [0] => name
    [1] => parent
    [2] => number
    [3] => chart_id
    [4] => type
    [5] => id
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Look into:

```
mysql_query('DESCRIBE '.$table);
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
SELECT @cCommand := GROUP_CONCAT( COLUMN_NAME ORDER BY column_name SEPARATOR ',\n')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';

SET @cCommand = CONCAT( 'SELECT ', @cCommand, ' from my_database.my_table;');
PREPARE xCommand from @cCommand;
EXECUTE xCommand;
```

Answer (score 4):

in mysql to get columns details and table structure by following keywords or queries

1.`DESC table_name`

2.`DESCRIBE table_name`

3.`SHOW COLUMNS FROM table_name`

4.`SHOW create table table_name;`

5.`EXPLAIN table_name`

Answer (score 3):

The MySQL function
describe table
should get you where you want to go (put your table name in for "table").  You'll have to parse the output some, but it's pretty easy.  As I recall, if you execute that query, the PHP query result accessing functions that would normally give you a key-value pair will have the column names as the keys.  But it's been a while since I used PHP so don't hold me to that. :)

Comment: There are some pretty good docs at php.net within http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-fields.php

Answer (score 3):

The [`mysql_list_fields`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-fields.php) function might interest you ; but, as the manual states :

> This function is deprecated. It is
>   preferable to use `mysql_query()` to
>   issue a SQL `SHOW COLUMNS FROM table [LIKE 'name']` statement instead.

Comment: How does the function work if it doesn't issue a SQL query to the server? Why is it being deprecated?

Answer (score 3):

You may also want to check out `mysql_fetch_array()`, as in:

```
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
//$row[0] = 'First Field';
//$row['first_field'] = 'First Field';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can get the entire table structure using following simple command.

```
DESC TableName
```

or you can use following query.

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$col = $db->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM category");

while ($fildss = $col->fetch_array())
{             
    $filds[] = '"{'.$fildss['Field'].'}"';
    $values[] = '$rows->'.$fildss['Field'].'';
}

if($type == 'value')
{
    return $values = implode(',', $values);
}
else {
     return $filds = implode(',', $filds);
}
```

Comment: To be more helpful to future users could you please provide some context for your answer, not just a code dump.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me..

```
$sql = "desc MyTableName";
$result = @mysql_query($sql);
while($row = @mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row[0]."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

mysqli fetch_field() worked for me:

```
if ($result = $mysqli -> query($sql)) {
  // Get field information for all fields
  while ($fieldinfo = $result -> fetch_field()) {
    printf("Name: %s\n", $fieldinfo -> name);
    printf("Table: %s\n", $fieldinfo -> table);
    printf("Max. Len: %d\n", $fieldinfo -> max_length);
  }
  $result -> free_result();
}
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/pHP/func_mysqli_fetch_field.asp

Answer (score 1):

The easy way, if loading results using assoc is to do this:

```
$sql = "SELECT p.* FROM (SELECT 1) as dummy LEFT JOIN `product_table` p on null";
$q = $this->db->query($sql);
$column_names = array_keys($q->row);
```

This you load a single result using this query, you get an array with the table column names as keys and null as value.
E.g.

```
Array(
'product_id' => null,
'sku' => null,
'price' => null,
...
)
```

after which you can easily get the table column names using the php function array_keys($result)

Answer (score 0):

I have write a simple php script to fetch table columns through PHP: 
[Show_table_columns.php](https://gist.github.com/hussnainsheikh/8bbc7236cc16139136ae2518b5b22f27)

```php
<?php
$db = 'Database'; //Database name
$host = 'Database_host'; //Hostname or Server ip
$user = 'USER'; //Database user
$pass = 'Password'; //Database user password
$con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
if ($con) {
    $link = mysql_select_db($db) or die("no database") . mysql_error();
    $count = 0;
    if ($link) {
        $sql = "
            SELECT column_name
            FROM   information_schema.columns
            WHERE  table_schema = '$db'
                   AND table_name = 'table_name'"; // Change the table_name your own table name
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
        if (mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
            echo $sql . "<br> <br>";
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
                echo "COLUMN " . ++$count . ": {$row[0]}<br>";
                $table_name = $row[0];
            }
            echo "<br>Total No. of COLUMNS: " . $count;
        } else {
            echo "Error in query.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Database not found.";
    }
} else {
    echo "Connection Failed.";
}
?>
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Please post the actual answer here and only use your gist as a backup/reference