# Concat a string to SELECT * MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, string, concatenation

The following query works fine with MySQL:

```
SELECT concat(title,'/') FROM `socials` WHERE 1
```

It Concat **/** to the selected title field.

However, when I try to do the following:

```
SELECT concat(*,'/') FROM `socials` WHERE 1
```

It returns the follwoing Error:

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*,'/') FROM `socials` WHERE 1 LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1
```

**So is there any way to make such sql query to work with MySql**

Comment: No, that can't be done in a plain select. Can you use a stored procedure?

Comment: No using stored procedure is not an option for me.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You simply can't do that in SQL. You have to explicitly list the fields and concat each one:

```
SELECT CONCAT(field1, '/'), CONCAT(field2, '/'), ... FROM `socials` WHERE 1
```

If you are using an app, you can use SQL to read the column names, and then use your app to construct a query like above. See this stackoverflow question to find the column names: [Get table column names in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526688/get-table-column-names-in-mysql)

Comment: Thank you all, but the most distinguishable aspect of this answer to obtain it as correct, is showing how to achieve selecting the multiple fields.

Comment: @sємsєм, you do it by listing them manually (or, if you are using an app, you can use SQL to read the columns, and then use your app to construct a query like above).

Answer (score 27):

If you want to concatenate the fields using / as a separator, you can use `concat_ws`:

```
select concat_ws('/', col1, col2, col3) from mytable
```

You cannot escape listing the columns in the query though. The *-syntax works only in "select * from". You can list the columns and construct the query dynamically though.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot concatenate multiple fields with a string. You need to select a field instand of all (`*`).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this on multiple fields. You can also look for [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Comment: Researchers shouldn't need to click a link to understand your advice.