# PHP MySQL getting both the result as well as the column name of the table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pivot-table

I have always been getting the results of a database but never the column name, now I have a situation where i need both the column name and result together.

I have a simple code that shows the column name and adjacent to it show results where the results are = 1.

So let's say my table is looking like this

```
  |  Science  |   Maths   |   Biology   |   English   |
---------------------------------------------------------
  |     1     |     0     |     0       |      1      |
```

So basically what I am looking for is something like

```
Table Name       |      Results
---------------------------------
Science          |          1
English          |          1
```

I search around the web and found the usage of INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS but that doesn't seem to work in the way I wanted it to. I somehow need to include both INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as well as select * WHERE user = $user kinda stuff.

My approach.

```
 $i = 0;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'trophy' WHERE UPPER(username) = UPPER('$searchuser')");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['COLUMN_NAME'];
    echo '-'
    echo $row[$i];
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: you want make a crossover query like MS Access does? What this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526688/get-table-column-names-in-mysql ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to approach this would probably be by fetching an associative array and using its keys. From your example it seems you always expect to get 1 result row, but to prevent problems I will add a `LIMIT 1` anyway. You could do something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trophy WHERE username = '$searchuser' LIMIT 1");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
foreach ($result as $name => $value)
  echo $name . '-' . $value;
```

Note that the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated though. You should use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli) or [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead. You can compare them [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: indeed, thanks, i am aware of the mysqli. But what i am looking for is to able to put column's name into an array

so i can use $row['COLUMN_NAME'];

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, **MYSQL_BOTH**)) {
    printf ("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row["name"]);
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: Did you notice that the query he tried will not result in anything? For what query are you fetching the results?