# Filter table with column name

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am working on a huge database. I want to find all the tables in all the database which contains columns name say "xyz" (cann't say actual column name). Is there any query or other way to solve the my problem. TIA

FYI 
DB : MySql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526688/get-table-column-names-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do that using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database:

```
SELECT 
  TABLE_SCHEMA, 
  TABLE_NAME 
FROM 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
  COLUMN_NAME ='xyz';
```

-for searching through all databases. If you want to do that only for your database, then add:

```
SELECT 
  TABLE_NAME 
FROM 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
  COLUMN_NAME ='xyz' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='database';
```

Of course, you can use `LIKE` comparison or any another thing (which is allowed in SQL) to filter your columns.