# MYSQL get Date column as string

Tags: c#, mysql

I am not sure my question has answer!
I have a MYSQL table with a date column. I want get it in C# as string not MYSQL date time
but matter is I don't know column Name.I know how do it if know column name

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(X, '%Y/%m/%d') AS  X FROM Y
```

but i don't know how do it when i don't know column Name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what MySql connector your using but assuming it's ADO compatible the following should work:

```
string dateString;
using (IDbConnection connection = new MySqlConnection()) {
    connection.ConnectionString = "YOUR STRING";
    connection.Open();
    try {
        using (IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(X, '%Y/%m/%d') AS  X FROM Y";
            using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
                dateString = reader.GetString(0);

                // Alternately you can read the data as a DateTime and use
                // .NET's formatting.
                //dateString = reader.GetDateTime(0).ToShortDateString();
            }
        }
    }
    finally {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

In response to clarification from your comment, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526688/get-table-column-names-in-mysql). You'll need to query the information_schema table and filter on the table name and data type.

Comment: thanks for your replay but my question is : "What's query if I don't know column name i.e X"