# Echo name of fields from MySQL table to web page

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

How do I display all field names from a MySQL table to a web page when I only know the table name?

Comment: how do i answer a question when i only have one sentence to go on

Comment: Are you able to make a connection to mysql?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get table column names in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526688/get-table-column-names-in-mysql)

Comment: Google search for "How do I display all field names from a MySQL table" would've yielded result #2 as [**this...** (Get table column names in mysql?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526688/get-table-column-names-in-mysql) which should have been marked as a duplicate.

Comment: The question also includes the part, 'How do I display all field names to a web page' and the links you provide do not do that.

Comment: @CChoma Yes, i can connect to MySQL what I want is an efficient way od displaying the fieldnames to a web page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `information_schema` meta-DB:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE (TABLE_SCHEMA='Yourdb') AND (TABLE_NAME = 'Yourtablename')
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @MarcB's suggestion, you can also do:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM table
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-columns.html

Comment: This would not work on a web page.  It would return "array" as many times as there are columns.

Comment: @Mark WTF? Sure it'd work on a web page. You'd just have to write the right code to handle the data MySQL returns.

Comment: Why not put that in your answer?

Comment: You mean where you insulted the author of this question?  I'd like to see more productive comments from a user with 90k+ rep.