# How to create a dynamic html table with php and sql database

Tags: php, html, sql, web

I want to make a dynamic html table that would display data from my database.
My database table looks like this:

```
 | name   | allowances | amount |
 |  jim   |   meal     |   900  |
 |  jim   |   fare     |   700  |
 |  alan  |   load     |   500  |
 | sohpie |   meal     |   900  |
 | sohpie |   load     |   500  |
```

I need my html table to display  this:

```
 | name   | meal  | load | fare |
 |  jim   |  900  |   0  |  700 |
 |  alan  |   0   |  500 |   0  |
 | sohpie |  900  |  500 |  900 |
```

my problem is how i am going to output the amount as `<td>` aligned  with the allowances as `<th>`.

Comment: show your php code. @rizaldy cordero

Comment: i thought my code  wasn't necessary because i am only new to php i was only able to retrieve the allowances as `<th>` . i dont know know what to do about the amount.

Comment: I guess the easiest option would be to build a bidimentional array to store all the data the way you want, then just cycle the array as you build the table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get table column names in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526688/get-table-column-names-in-mysql)