# Use PHP to get Column Names and Data for CSV export (MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, database, csv

I am in need of a way to export my MYSQL Database to CSV via PHP, but I need to select the column names as well. So Far I have the following which does everything I need except get the column names.

```
echo "Export Starting \n";
$SQL = ("SELECT *
FROM INF_TimeEntries
WHERE Exported IS NULL");
$result = mysqli_query($db_conn, $SQL) or die("Selection Error " . mysqli_error($db_conn));
echo "Export Data Selected \n";
$fp = fopen('../updateDatabase/timesheetExport/TimeEntries.csv', 'w');
echo "Starting Write to CSV \n";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
    $RowID = $row['ID'];
    $exportTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $sql = ("UPDATE INF_TimeEntries
                    SET Exported = '$exportTime'
                    WHERE ID = '$RowID'");
    if ($mysqli_app->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    }
    else {
        echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."\n";
        echo "An Error Occured please contact the administrator ". $mysqli_app->error."\n";
    }
}
echo "Export Completed \n";
fclose($fp);
mysqli_close($mysqli_app);
mysqli_close($db_conn);
```

I am not sure how I would go about Achieving this. I do not simply need to get column names but Column names and the data contained in each of these columns. I have not found any information on this in the other question suggested.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get table column names in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526688/get-table-column-names-in-mysql)

Comment: I read this article and found it did not really help me. Hence why I posted my own question

Comment: You seemingly want the column names (and as you commented on an answer given, not hardcoded), and that question answers how to get the column names of a table dynamically. So is your question not how to get column names now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using `mysqli_fetch_assoc`, the name of the columns are the keys of the `$row` array in each iteration. You can put that in the file in the first iteration:

```
echo "Starting Write to CSV \n";
$first = true;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if ($first) {
        fputcsv($fp, array_keys($row));
        $first = false;
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
    // ..
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you have your `$result` set from your `mysqli_query()` method, you can use [`mysqli_fetch_fields()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php) to return an array of descriptions of the columns in the result set.

Each element of that array is a an object with several properties. One property is `name` -- which you can use as a header for your csv file. You also get properties like `max_length`, `length`, and `table`.  The [linked documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php) shows an example of using this metadata.

This metadata is especially useful if you have a query more complex than `SELECT * FROM table`: if you assign aliases to the columns in your query, they show up in the `name` properties of the metadata array elements.

This works even if the result set has no rows in it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds pretty simple, as long as everything else is already working for you. You can create an array with the column names, and `fputcsv($fp, $array_of_column_names)` right before your while loop.

Comment: How would I get the array of the column names? I would prefer not to hard code it.

Comment: Look at the database using an admin interface like phpmyadmin or mysql workbench.

Comment: I replied to your comment before you edited it. If you don't want to hard code it, the linked possible duplicate does show how to do it. How to select the columns, that is; not necessarily how to append them to a CSV.

Comment: On second thought, the other two answers offer better options than running another query to get the column names.