# how to get field names if results is empty? [PHP-Codeigniter]

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I was able to take the field name from the table using `array_keys()`
but if the query results are empty, `array_keys()` can not be used.

[image: query results]

is there any other way that I can take the name of the field even if the result is empty?

[image: query result empty]

Query i used:

```
SELECT m.nama_user, m.nama_login, m.email, m.tgl_expired, m.password_web, gu.ucode_grp, gu.nama_grp_user
FROM tb_m_user m
LEFT OUTER JOIN tb_m_grp_user gu
ON m.ucode_grp=gu.ucode_grp
WHERE id_user=10
```

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526688/get-table-column-names-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

In Codeigniter you can use...

```
$field_names = $this->db->list_fields('name_of_your_table');
```

**name_of_your_table** is the name of the Database Table you want the field list from.

**$field_name**s will be an array with the field names

For more Details, Refer to https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/db_driver_reference.html?highlight=field%20names#CI_DB_driver::list_fields

Comment: but not all fields in the table I want to take. query that I use like this SELECT m.nama_user, m.nama_login, m.email, m.tgl_expired, m.password_web, gu.ucode_grp, gu.nama_grp_user
            FROM tb_m_user m
            LEFT OUTER JOIN tb_m_grp_user gu
            ON m.ucode_grp=gu.ucode_grp
            WHERE id_user=10

Comment: if you already know what field names you wanna get, why bother selecting it from the db? that sounds illogical and a waste of a resource. just hard code it into an array or something.

Comment: @RisingSun when columns are aliased like in CONCAT('name', ' ', 'surname') as personal_data it doesn't sound like a waste to me at all

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
For eg.
`$query_string = 'select name, role from sampledata';`

`$this->db->query($query_string)->list_fields();`

o/p is, `Array ( [0] => name [1] => role)`

Answer (score 0):

Get the query result object

```
$result = $this->db->get(); // OR $this->db->query()
```

and simply use it's methods to get all the data you need:

```
$return = array();
$return['list_fields'] = $result->list_fields();
$return['data'] = $result->result_array();
$return['num_rows'] = $result->num_rows();
```