# How to change datatype for many columns at once in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

We started with ID as int(11).  Then we switched to Hibernate column auto generation and the ID became bigint(20).  So, many foreign keys stopped working unless I change the join column definition from bigint(20) to int (11).  Is it possible to write a script that changes all int(11) to bigint (20) for all columns?

The query to find all columns to change is as follows:

```
select table_name, column_name, column_type 
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'rentoptimum' 
  and column_type='int(11)'
order by table_name, ordinal_position;
```

Can I update data in the information_schema.columns or I should write the alter script for every table?

Comment: do you mean create `alter table` statements? You can check [**information schema**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526688/get-table-column-names-in-mysql) and create dynamic query.

Comment: That's what I thought, how?

Comment: But what is the problem? Query the information schema or create the dynamic query. Tell me more to guide you on the right direction.

Comment: Please, see the edit to my post, it has a question

Comment: Well you like to take shortcuts, dont you? The true is I dont know, I wouldnt take the risk and write the proper `ALTER`  query instead.  Maybe you can get away with change the type, but not sure if the db check for the conversion constraint.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza information_schema does not have tables, those are system views and are not updateable. Proper alter table statements are the only way out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` to dynamically generate a script with the `ALTER TABLE` statements needed to modify these column data types.

You need to be very careful to only modify the data type, and not any other attributes of the column (nullability, auto_increment, signed/unsigned, etc).

Here is an example to get you started. This will generate one `ALTER TABLE` statement per table in a given schema, even if it has multiple columns to modify. It will replace `int(11)` with `bigint(11)`, which is slightly different than what you asked for, but the `(11)` doesn't affect the actual data type. You can tweak that if you want.

```
select concat('alter table `',t.table_schema,'`.`',t.table_name,'`',
  group_concat(' modify column `',c.column_name,'` ',replace(c.column_type,'int','bigint'),
  if(c.is_nullable='yes',' null',' not null '),c.extra),';') as the_ddl 
into outfile '/tmp/so42114820.sql'
from information_schema.columns c 
  inner join information_schema.tables t on t.table_schema = c.table_schema and t.table_name = c.table_name
where t.table_schema = 'your_schema' 
  and t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
  and c.data_type = 'int' 
group by t.table_schema,t.table_name;

set @foreign_key_checks = @@foreign_key_checks;
set foreign_key_checks = 0;

\. /tmp/so42114820.sql

set foreign_key_checks = @foreign_key_checks;
```

Comment: Thanks, getting the error errno: 150 - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Comment: You will need to drop the foreign keys before changing the data types, and then re-add them afterwards.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did, Hibernate create foreign keys  anyways