# HTML form with CRUD operations for MySQL database when columns are >300

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am working on a science project, which would store (and further do other functions) some values for CD Markers (these are around 350). My table structure is like -

```
_id
diagnosis
remarks
CD1
CD2
CD3a
CD3b
CDw4
...
CD348
CD349
CD350
```

I know, these many columns in a table are usually not recommended and some would say to use multiple tables and store values in rows. I have tried those, and those are not matching my requirement, so for the time-being I am stuck with this option only.

Now, if the columns were less I could have created a simple HTML form and used PHP, MySQLi for CRUD operations. But with these many columns it would be time consuming task to type HTML code individually. **So, I am searching for a way if I can generate a HTML form using some PHP Loop to enumerate table's columns with one textbox, and further create the insert query using similar loop.**

My sample insert query is like (copied from my phpmyadmin)-

```
INSERT INTO `fcm_markers` (`_id`, `diagnosis`, `remarks`, `CD1a`, `CD1b`, `CD1c`, `CD1d`, `CD1e`, `CD2`, `CD3`, `CD3d`, `CD3e`, `CD3g`, `CD4`, `CD5`, `CD6`, `CD7`, `CD8a`, `CD8b`, `CD9`, `CD10`, `CD11a`, `CD11b`, `CD11c`, `CD11d`, `CDw12`, `CD13`, `CD14`, `CD15`, `CD16`, `CD16b`, `CD17`, `CD18`, `CD19`, `CD20`, `CD21`, `CD22`, `CD23`, `CD24`, `CD25`, `CD26`, `CD27`, `CD28`, `CD29`, `CD30`, `CD31`, `CD32a`, `CD32b`, `CD32c`, `CD33`, `CD34`, `CD35`, `CD36`, `CD37`, `CD38`, `CD39`, `CD40`, `CD41`, `CD42a`, `CD42b`, `CD42c`, `CD42d`, `CD43`, `CD44`, `CD45RA`, `CD45RB`, `CD45RC`, `CD45RO`, `CD46`, `CD47`, `CD48`, `CD49a`, `CD49b`, `CD49c`, `CD49d`, `CD49e`, `CD49f`, `CD50`, `CD51`, `CD52`, `CD53`, `CD54`, `CD55`, `CD56`, `CD57`, `CD58`, `CD59`, `CD60a`, `CD61`, `CD62E`, `CD62L`, `CD62P`, `CD63`, `CD64a`, `CD65`, `CD65s`, `CD66a`, `CD66b`, `CD66c`, `CD66d`, `CD66e`, `CD66f`, `CD68`, `CD69`, `CD70`, `CD71`, `CD72`, `CD73`, `CD74`, `CD75`, `CD75S`, `CD77`, `CD79a`, `CD79b`, `CD80`, `CD81`, `CD82`, `CD83`, `CD84`, `CD85A`, `CD85C`, `CD85D`, `CD85E`, `CD85F`, `CD85G`, `CD85H`, `CD85I`, `CD85J`, `CD85K`, `CD86`, `CD87`, `CD88`, `CD89`, `CD90`, `CD91`, `CD92`, `CD93`, `CD94`, `CD95`, `CD96`, `CD97`, `CD98`, `CD99`, `CD99R`, `CD100`, `CD101`, `CD102`, `CD103`, `CD104`, `CD105`, `CD106`, `CD107a`, `CD107b`, `CD108`, `CD109`, `CD110`, `CD111`, `CD112`, `CD113`, `CD114`, `CD115`, `CD116`, `CD117`, `CD118`, `CD119`, `CD120a`, `CD120b`, `CD121a`, `CD121b`, `CD122`, `CD123`, `CD124`, `CD125`, `CD126`, `CD127`, `CD129`, `CD130`, `CD131`, `CD132`, `CD133`, `CD134`, `CD135`, `CD136`, `CD137`, `CD138`, `CD139`, `CD140a`, `CD140b`, `CD141`, `CD142`, `CD143`, `CD144`, `CDw145`, `CD146`, `CD147`, `CD148`, `CD150`, `CD151`, `CD152`, `CD153`, `CD154`, `CD155`, `CD156a`, `CD156b`, `CD156c`, `CD157`, `CD158a`, `CD158b1`, `CD158b2`, `CD158d`, `CD158e1/e2`, `CD158f`, `CD158g`, `CD158h`, `CD158i`, `CD158j`, `CD158k`, `CD159a`, `CD159c`, `CD160`, `CD161`, `CD162`, `CD163`, `CD164`, `CD165`, `CD166`, `CD167a`, `CD168`, `CD169`, `CD170`, `CD171`, `CD172a`, `CD172b`, `CD172g`, `CD173`, `CD174`, `CD175`, `CD175s`, `CD176`, `CD177`, `CD178`, `CD179a`, `CD179b`, `CD180`, `CD181`, `CD182`, `CD183`, `CD184`, `CD185`, `CD186`, `CD191`, `CD192`, `CD193`, `CD194`, `CD195`, `CD196`, `CD197`, `CDw198`, `CDw199`, `CD200`, `CD201`, `CD202b`, `CD203c`, `CD204`, `CD205`, `CD206`, `CD207`, `CD208`, `CD209`, `CD210a`, `CDw210b`, `CD212`, `CD213a1`, `CD213a2`, `CD215`, `CD217`, `CD218a`, `CD218b`, `CD220`, `CD221`, `CD222`, `CD223`, `CD224`, `CD225`, `CD226`, `CD227`, `CD228`, `CD229`, `CD230`, `CD231`, `CD232`, `CD233`, `CD234`, `CD235a`, `CD235b`, `CD236`, `CD236R`, `CD238`, `CD239`, `CD240`, `CD241`, `CD242`, `CD243`, `CD244`, `CD245`, `CD246`, `CD247`, `CD248`, `CD249`, `CD252`, `CD253`, `CD254`, `CD256`, `CD257`, `CD258`, `CD261`, `CD262`, `CD263`, `CD264`, `CD265`, `CD266`, `CD267`, `CD268`, `CD269`, `CD270`, `CD271`, `CD272`, `CD273`, `CD274`, `CD275`, `CD276`, `CD277`, `CD278`, `CD279`, `CD280`, `CD281`, `CD282`, `CD283`, `CD284`, `CD286`, `CD288`, `CD289`, `CD290`, `CD292`, `CDw293`, `CD294`, `CD295`, `CD296`, `CD297`, `CD298`, `CD299`, `CD300a`, `CD300c`, `CD300e`, `CD301`, `CD302`, `CD303`, `CD304`, `CD305`, `CD306`, `CD307a`, `CD307b`, `CD307c`, `CD307d`, `CD307e`, `CD309`, `CD312`, `CD314`, `CD315`, `CD316`, `CD317`, `CD318`, `CD319`, `CD320`, `CD321`, `CD322`, `CD324`, `CD325`, `CD326`, `CD327`, `CD328`, `CD329`, `CD331`, `CD332`, `CD333`, `CD334`, `CD335`, `CD336`, `CD337`, `CD338`, `CD339`, `CD340`, `CD344`, `CD349`, `CD350`, `CD351`, `CD352`, `CD353`, `CD354`, `CD355`, `CD357`, `CD358`, `CD359`, `CD360`, `CD361`, `CD362`, `CD363`) VALUES (NULL, 'neutro', 'wbc', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1');
```

As one can see, the CD numbers are not regular (some have suffix a,b,c; some have prefix w, some numbers do not exist), so I can't just loop CD1-CD150 or something like this.

Comment: Any time you find yourself with enumerated columns (above 2, say), you can be sure that your schema is suboptimal. If normalisation is not an option, then neither is a relational database

Comment: @Strawberry I am a medical doctor, not a professional programmer,will you please suggest me any alternate way of doing this or any article to read about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bottomline: Use an ORM, it will save you a ton of time and effort**, but if you are going for a pure approach:

Check this on how to [Get table column names in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526688/get-table-column-names-in-mysql)

Then, with a simple `foreach` you can create the form fields (sample follows);

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"{$value}\">";
}
```

The trick to saving data from this form is to name your HTML fields (`<input name="something">`), exactly the same as your database fields. Then, when POSTing the data to PHP, it can do the ditry work for you (sample code below).

```
$data = $_POST;
$keys = array(); $values=array();
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    array_push($keys, $key);
    array_push($values, $value);
}
$keys = implode(',', $keys);
$values = implode(',', $values);

$query = "INSERT INTO fcm_makers ({$keys}) VALUES ({$values})";
```

Comment: A sticking plaster for an axe wound.

Comment: How can I learn about ORM and how to use it in my project (sorry, I am a medical doctor, not professional programmer, I learn coding only in my time)