# How do I convert a JSON object into a MySQL row?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, go, struct

I'd like to take a JSON string representing an object from a 3rd party API and insert it into a MySQL table. The JSON object properties match the table fields 1-to-1. There are several hundred columns in this table/JSON object. And there will be a few dozen rows to insert at any time.

I'd rather not make a huge struct. But if I need to, then I'd rather not `db.Prepare()` an INSERT statement with several hundred "?"s. But if I have to then I'd rather not Have to write a `stmt.Exec()` with several hundred parameters.

Is there a good way to do this in golang? Or is it just going to be extremely inefficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following given a slice of valid database field names `fieldNames` and JSON data `data`:

```
var j map[string]interface{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &j); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
var names []string
var inserts []string
var values []interface{}
for _, n := range fieldNames {
    if v, ok := j[n]; ok {
        names = append(names, n)
        inserts = append(inserts, "?")
        values = append(values, v)
    }
}
statement := "insert into yourTable (" +
    strings.Join(names, ", ") +
    ") values (" + strings.Join(inserts, ", ") + ")"
err := db.Exec(statement, values...)
```

To avoid SQL injection attacks, it's important to work from a slice of known column names.

You can query the database to create the `fieldNames` slice.  See [Get table column names in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526688/get-table-column-names-in-mysql) for the query required.

If the column names and JSON names are different, then replace the slice with a map where the keys are the column names and the values are the JSON names:

```
fieldNames := map[string]string{
  "column1": "json1",
  ... and so on
}

var j map[string]interface{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &j); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
var names []string
var inserts []string
var values []interface{}
for dbName, jsonName := range fieldNames {
    if v, ok := j[jsonName]; ok {
        names = append(names, dbName)
        inserts = append(inserts, "?")
        values = append(values, v)
    }
}
statement := "insert into yourTable (" +
    strings.Join(names, ", ") +
    ") values (" + strings.Join(inserts, ", ") + ")"
err := db.Exec(statement, values...)
```

Comment: So, I still need to create a `fieldNames` that has the field names? and it can't be snake_case (cuz that's what they are)?

Regardless of if I go this way, thanks for showing me some interesting Go that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: The above code works with snake_case names. The only requirement is that the JSON property names match the table field names. Query the database to get the field names.  See [Get table column names in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526688/get-table-column-names-in-mysql) for an example of the queries to use.

Comment: Thanks, I expanded on your example to fit my needs. Specifically, I used a switch to handle different fields differently. I might post my code later, but I'd need to remove IP. Am I correct in understanding that this is not type safe? And that I need to use a struct for type safety? I might post a separate question on that