# Update Table Iterating Array Using PHP / PDO

Tags: php, pdo

There are similar questions here and some rather complex answers. I don't believe it should be that complicated. Perhaps it is. I am new to PDO. I have an array of key-value pairs. I need to update a record with those values. Is there a more intelligent way to do this?

```
$sql = "UPDATE Table SET ? = ? WHERE ID = ?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
foreach($QueryString as $Key=>$Value)
{
    $stmt->execute($Key, $Value, $RecordID);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't bind a value to a column name, so your current code won't work at all. It would also be more efficient to form that query to make all the updates at once, for example:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Table SET";
$v = 0;
foreach ($QueryString as $Key=>$Value) {
    if ($v++ > 0) $sql .= ',';
    $sql .= " `$Key` = ?";
}
$sql .= " WHERE ID = ?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array_merge(array_values($QueryString), array($RecordID)));
```

Note that this query is still vulnerable to injection if the keys of the `$QueryString` array come from an outside source. To avoid this issue, you should check that the columns actually exist, either using a manually specified whitelist e.g.

```
$colnames = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'];
foreach ($QueryString as $Key=>$Value) {
    if (!in_array($Key, $colnames)) {
        // abort
    }
    if ($v++ > 0) $sql .= ',';
    $sql .= " `$Key` = ?";
}
```

or by getting the list of the column names from the `information_schema.columns` table as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526688/get-table-column-names-in-mysql) and using the result of that query as your whitelist.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: Like your way of handling the end comma also. I'm always doing a substr on the final string to delete it. Always thought there must be a better way.

Comment: Apologies, missed the second part. Reverted.

Comment: @RationalRabbit another way I like to deal with it is to create an array e.g. `$upd[] = " \`$Key\` = ?";` and then `$sql .= implode(',', $upd);`